# Event handling with subclasses

Tags: javascript, requirejs, browserify

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33981728/event-handling-in-es6-classes).
I'm moving from RequireJS to browserify (together with babelify) and try to rewrite my current modules to classes. For each of my RequireJS modules I have a method called `eventHandler` which handles all general module specific events. Now when I extend a class, the parent class calls the subclass`s `eventHandler` method which leads to invoking the method twice.

There's another problem with my current code, though. I've also two methods on several modules to bind and unbind events. The site I'm working on is a responsive site which shares the same JS across all device sizes. On some screen sizes (breakpoints) I want to bind some specific events, on others I mustn't (or even unbind them when coming from another breakpoint). 
So a typical module would look more or less like this:

```
'use strict';

let specificEventsBound = false;

class Tooltip {
    constructor() {
        this.eventHandler();
    }

   eventHandler() {
        // bind general events across all breakpoints
    }

    bindSpecificEvents() {
        // bind breakpoint specific events
        specificEventsBound = true;
    }

    unbindSpecificEvents() {
        // unbind breakpoint specific events
        specificEventsBound = false;
    }

    checkBreakpoint() {
        if(someBreakpoint) {
            this.bindSpecificEvents();
        } else {
            this.unbindSpecificEvents();
        }
    } 
}

module.exports = Tooltip;
```

When I now extend this class and implement a `checkBreakpoint` with a different `someBreakpoint` in the subclass, the `bindSpecificEvents` and `unbindSpecificEvents` will still get called when the super methods get invoked. I think I have to change how I'm handling the events right now... Could you suggest me on how to properly handle this? Perhaps a separate class just for event handling with registering and detaching methods?

Comment: What do you mean by *"When I know extend this class and implement a checkBreakpoint with a different someBreakpoint in the subclass, the bindSpecificEvents and unbindSpecificEvents will still get called when the super methods get invoked."*? In `Tooltip`, calls to `this.checkBreakpoint` will call the actual `checkBreakpoint` on the instance, which will be the one defined by the class that was instantiated (e.g., the subclass).

Answer (score 1):

> When I now extend this class and implement a `checkBreakpoint` with a different someBreakpoint in the subclass, the `bindSpecificEvents` and `unbindSpecificEvents` will still get called when the `super` methods get invoked.

You may have a misunderstanding here. Even in superclass code, `this.checkBreakpoint` will look up the `checkBreakpoint` property on the object, find it on the object's immediate prototype (the subclass's), and call that version of `checkBreakpoint`.

Here's a simpler example ([*live copy on Babel's REPL*](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?experimental=false&evaluate=true&loose=false&spec=true&code=class%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20constructor()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.method1()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20method1()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20this.method2()%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%20%20method2()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Base%23method2%22)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Aclass%20Derived%20extends%20Base%20%7B%0A%20%20method2()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log(%22Derived%23method2%22)%3B%0A%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Anew%20Derived%3B)):

```
class Base {
  constructor() {
    this.method1();
  }
  method1() {
    this.method2();
  }
  method2() {
    console.log("Base#method2");
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
  method2() {
    console.log("Derived#method2");
  }
}

new Derived;
```

Output:

```
Derived#method2
```

Note how the call in `Base#method1` to `this.method2` calls `Derived#method2`, not `Base#method2`. This is vital to polymorphism.

Comment: Ah stupid, I assumed both get called.. Thank you! But anyway, could you advise me how would you better handle a situation like this?

Comment: @enyce12: (Not stupid.) By default, only the "latest" one in the inheritance series will get called. It can, of course, call `super.checkBreakpoint()` if it thinks it should (this is part of the reason for the new syntactic sugar, supercalls were hard before), but if it doesn't the super's very never gets called. I'm not really sure what the problem with your current approach is that you're trying to solve. From what little I understand, it seems fine, other than perhaps some naming (I wouldn't call something that *sets up* event handlers `eventHandler`; that sounds like it *is* one).

Comment: What I actually want to achieve is this: http://tinyurl.com/pctmjm4. But instead of directly creating a new instance I wanted to profit from inheritance... But I think it's not going to work the way I want it to.